# Android Studio Gradle build errors with login activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having these weird errors, and I am unable to fix it. All I did was create a new login activity and this problem occurs.

[image]

I have read that I have to migrate to GoogleApiClient, but I have no idea how to 'migrate' to it...I installed Android Studio today as well and everything is brand new. I just really want to start doing some app development, but this is in my way.

Here is a related error as well
[image]

UPDATE:
I have changed the version of the google play services in gradle dependencies, but now this error is shown.
[image]

Comment: Have you done a gradle refresh to pull down dependencies? If that doesn't work, try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: How do I do a gradle refresh?

Comment: The Gradle sidebar in Android studio, there's a refresh symbol at the top-left of that screen. Otherwise just run the clean/dependencies task through the task list

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I'm actually having trouble finding the symbol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are not including the google play services lib in your gradle dependencies, is that put it into your app gradle file (dependencies section)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

Then Sync, Clean and Rebuild, and should work.

Regards

Comment: In my build. gradle I have these lines dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}

Comment: sync, clean and rebuild process?

Comment: I'm still having the error, I will post more screen shots to detail the problem

Comment: ok. Sometimes you have to invalidate cache( File-InvalidateCache/Restart), i dont know why Android Studio save that, but maybe should be that. Try to put the google play services version i put, if problem stills, may be some other thing wrong

Comment: I have tried to do that with the earlier suggestion, but still no fix and I have posted a new picture that relates to the problem.

Comment: Okay, I tried your suggestion of changing the version, and now I get a new set of errors.

Comment: what libraries have in the libs folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87623/discussion-between-user3718584-and-max-pinto).