# How do I 'miragte' GoogleApiClient to Android Studio?

Tags: android

So, today I recently downloaded the latest version of Android Studio and when I created a login activity page (my very first activity created :D), I got this weird gradle build error saying

**"Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlayServicesClient"**

**"Cannot resolve symbol PlusClient"**

So I did some research and it has come to me that these packages are not supported anymore and after doing some further research I came upon this notice below

**Note: If you have an existing app that connects to Google Play services with a subclass of GooglePlayServicesClient, you should migrate to GoogleApiClient as soon as possible**

Now, my question is this and sorry if this sounds very stupid, but please understand that I am still a total amateur at this. Back to the point, my question is how do I migrate to GoogleApiClient?

What am I supposed to replace

**import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;**

**import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;**

with?

I have been suggested to change the version of my google play services to a lower version, but I want to stay on the latest version.

EDIT:
Why am I getting down voted so fast? Is my question too stupid or something?

Comment: Well, I have been suggested to lower the version of googleplayservices, which does get around the issue, but it doesn't really solve it. Out of all the stackvoerflow threads with this problem, the answer is that I should change to using the GoogleApiClient and that googleplayservices is deprecated now. However, I'm not sure how to change to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the [Google+ Platform for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/), which goes through all of the available APIs. The [Getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) goes through creating a connection using `GoogleApiClient` and [Plus.API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus.html#API), the replacement for `PlusClient`.

Answer (score 1):

try to put this into your app gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

then Sync-Clean-Rebuild project.

To update and apply changes.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151241/android-studio-gradle-build-errors-with-login-activity/32151334#32151334)

Comment: Max, you do realize that's me right? I'm jsut asking to see if there was an alternate solution to lowering the version.